# Error installing Spyder in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Tried anaconda today , it seems fine but when I tried to launch Spyder each time I get this error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 23, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.external import lockfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\lockfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "C:\Users\Jaker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from . import _pswindows as _psplatform
  File "C:\Users\Jaker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_windows as cext
ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_windows'`

Any help regarding this ? Also how do I get python 3.6.3 in anaconda..?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two Python versions installed in your system: one in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\` and the other in `C:\Users\Jaker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36`.

Please uninstall one of them and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Well I uninstalled it and tried but no luck . Also is python 3.6.3 will be available through anaconda ?